# For Notification Push,the Real iPhone device does not display the Approval Alert when the App first loaded

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm a new in iOS development.

I have a app which like to receive Notification push, i generated the certificate, registered my iPhone as a device, create a App ID, and generate the profile. By now, I'm able to build/debug in my iPhone(iOS 5.0.1, my iPhone is JeailBreaked).
Then in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I add below code:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

With this code, I wish when the app is first loaded, it can pop up a alert to promote Approve/DisApprove to receive the Notification Push.   But nothing is pop up.

I'm not quite sure about the profile file. May be I need to do something about it? Or did I missed some other thing?

Thanks All,

Benroo

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Team Provisioning Profile perhaps?  Notifications will not work with these, you must set it to a specific profile for that app identifier.  Check the delegate method

```
– application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved. I need to create a new profile file. And delete the old from xCode Orginazer, and to import the new one.